# Apex ERROR in the variable

Tags: trigger

```
trigger batchtoquotelineitem on Batch__c (After insert)
{
list<Quote_Line_Item__c> quo=new list<Quote_Line_Item__c>();
for (batch__c b:trigger.new)
{
Quote_Line_Item__c quotelineitem=new Quote_Line_Item__c();
AggregateResult[] groupedResults=[select MAX(batch_value__c)b from batch__c where id='Quote_Line_Item__c'];
decimal avgAmount = groupedResults[0].get('b');
quotelineitem.max_batch__c=avgAmout;
}
}
```

i am getting the error

> Compile Error: Variable does not exist: avgAmout at line 9 column 28

help me to get rid of the error

Comment: fyi: you can select answers as the solution to your question by clicking the V icon under the vote score of an answer. This will indicate to other users that you no longer need help on this.

Answer (score 5):

When developing, the errors you receive often point you directly to what's wrong. Have you even tried to see what could be the problem ?

```
decimal avgAmount = groupedResults[0].get('b');
quotelineitem.max_batch__c=avgAmout;
```

> Compile Error: Variable does not exist: avgAmout at line 9 column 28

Your variable avgAmout does not exist, because it is a typo, your variable is declared as avgAmount.